# Dell XPS 9550 Dedicated GPU Fuse

Tags: hardware-failure, dell-xps

On my dell XPS 9550 the dedicated GPU burned out due to heat sync issues. The GPU is dead, but the integrated GPU still works, so the laptop generally works. However, after the GPU burned out, the keyboard stopped working after sleep. The keyboard works fine in BIOS and in Windows after restart, but does not come back from S3 sleep and Hibernation. Restarting the laptop fixes the issue. I suspect this is due to conflicts with the dead 960 GPU. I would like to disable the dedicated GPU entirely. There must be a fuse somewhere on the board for the GPU. Can anyone help me find it. Board diagrams would help.

Thank you!

Comment: It sounds like the GPU is already dead.  It isn't clear what additional destruction would affect.  It seems like any further disabling needs to be done in software/firmware.

Comment: The GPU is dead for sure, but I have a theory that it still pulls nominal voltage. The power handling chip on the board probably has an order in which it wakes up devices from sleep, and it probably wakes up the keyboard after the GPU. Because the GPU is kind of in the "zombi" stage right now, the power chip is trying to wake it up instead of just moving on to the keyboard. This is a total guess. I could test it by pulling off the GPU all together, but, again, need an infrared rework thing to do that right.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend not doing this or making any alternate attempt of the same fashion as much like a surgeon... one false move!

You’d also not necessarily be solving the problem. By disabling a ‘fuse’ you’re probably doing as much as disabling the windows driver for the GPU. Happy to be corrected and if I’m wrong will happily remove my answer

Comment: I am not worried about the "one false move" problem. I assemble surface mount components regularly, and have a microscope and tools for the job. As for the disabling of the GPU via drivers, I did that, uninstalled the Nvidia drivers all together, but the keyboard issue still persists, and I suspect it's related. It's probably a power management issue. Removing all power to the GPU would be worth a try. As is now the computer has no sleep function, and without that I might as well just replace the main board. I would swap the GPU, but don't have the tools to do that :(